# Vote system to my discord bot with nodejs

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm making a command .report @user  that creates a simple poll with 2 buttons added "agree" and "disagree". After certain time i want the bot to register user if agree's is more than disagree.

How can i make my bot count the results of voting after 7 days and then based on this either register on DB an user or send "Report Voting Failed".

What I hope is to be able to store the expiration date of the voting and that on that date the voting stops working and the corresponding action is taken.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()` for this. `setTimeout()` takes in two parameters. One, a function which holds your code that will be ran after the time has passed. Two, the amount of time in milliseconds to wait before executing your code.
Here is an example of how to use this.

```js
console.log('1') // will console.log 1 instantly
setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('2') // will console.log 2 after 1 second.
},
1000) // 1s = 1000ms
```

Furthermore, you can use buttons to accomplish the task of reporting. Check out [the guide on buttons](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#building-and-sending-buttons) for more info. Once a button is pushed, see whether it is an `Agree` or `Disagree` then do what you must from there. After the seven days is up, make the buttons unable to press, or whatever you want.
You might want to employ a node.js module such as `ms` to convert `7d` into ms. This could be useful as 7 days in milliseconds is 604,800,000. Using `ms`,
you could do

```js
const sevenDays = ms('7d') // returns 604800000
```

and then pass that into your `setTimeout()` function.
like so:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('The seven days has passed')
}, sevenDays)
```

Note however your bot will need to stay online for the duration of these 7 days, otherwise it will not run as it has forgotten that the `setTimeout()` function was used in an earlier instance.